# Why was R designed as a 1-starting indexes language?

Tags: programming-languages, domain-specific-languages

Spawning from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3420043/85579):

> We *usually* don't care whether indices start at $0$ or $1$ (except in the sense we'd rather start with our favourite if it doesn't matter, and the old joke is that [set theorists start at $0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#Definition_as_von_Neumann_ordinals) and non-[Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation) number theorists [start at $1$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html)). I say *usually*, because there are a few cases where we do:
>
> - [...]
> - [...]
> - If there's programming involved, use the same indexing for your mathematical exposition as in the code itself, [which varies by language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering#Usage_in_programming_languages). For example, Python starts at $0$, whereas R starts at $1$.

Why did they choose to start from $1$?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135325/why-do-vector-indices-in-r-start-with-1-instead-of-0) SO question.

Comment: Until further clarification, I'll take that your reference is not to the question but to these [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135349/1737973) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135441/1737973) answers.

Comment: Compatibility with Fortran and Matlab?

Comment: Compatibility with Mathematica?  In any case, counting starts at 1, there is no doubt about it ... measuring starts at 0 ...

Comment: Also, if you index from 1 to n, n is also the number of elements in the set you indexed ...

Comment: I love your comments and I'll love your answers.